# BackgroundWorker Still Blocks IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

So I have UI to create a calendar event within my app. When a new event is created I create notifications for all my users (around 3,000). I new this would take a while because I need to write to the database for each user to create their notification, so I created a class that inherits from `BackgroundWorker`. I don't really care if the notifications are created (I do, but not in the context of getting the request finished for the end user) so I thought this would be a valid approach.

When I went to implement it however, even after calling `context.Response.End()`, the `HttpHandler` still waits for the background worker to finish. I debugged the threads and `HttpHandler` and `BackgroundWorker` have different thread ids. I am not sure if I am somehow blacking the `HttpHandler` from returning or if I misunderstood what the `BackgroundWorker` class is for.

```
class EventHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    ...
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         ...
         // I need this to finish before the response ends
         CalendarEvent event = CreateCalendarEvent();
         List<int> users = GetUsersFromDB();
         if(event != null) // The event was created successfully so create the notifications
         {
             // This may take a while and does not effect the UI on
             // client side, so it can run in the background
             NotificationBackgroundWorker notificationWorker = new NotificationBackgroundWorker(notification, users);
             notificationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
         } else {
            ...
            // Log Error and set status code for response
            ...
         }
         ...
         context.Response.End()
    }
    ...
}

class NotificationBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    private Notification notification;
    private List<int> users;

    public NotificationBackgroundWorker(Notification newNotification, List<int> usersToNotify) : base()
    {
        this.notification = newNotification;
        this.users = usersToNotify;
        this.DoWork += DoNotificationWork;
    }

    private void DoNotificationWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        CreateUserNotifications(notification, users);
    }

    private void CreateUserNotifications(Notification notification, List<int> userList)
    {
        // This is where the bottleneck is occurring because there 
        // is one DB write per user
        foreach (int userId in userList)
        {
            ...
            // Create the notification for each user
            ...
        }
     }
}
```

Any insight would be awesome. Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Given the likelihood of a backlog of notifications and the way that IIS manages threads for websites, I'd be inclined to move the notifications off to a Windows service.

Comment: Personally, I do think that a `BackgroundWorker` should be used in a Windows GUI application (WinForms, WPF) only.

Comment: So I think Uwe is right, background worker was originally intended to be used in native applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` integrates with the current `SynchronizationContext`. It has been designed in such a way that it doesn't let the current request end before the `BackgroundWorker` is finished. This is what you want most of the time.

I suggest you queue your work item to the thread-pool by starting a new `Task`.

Comment: So using a task worked perfect. I have my modified DoNotificationWork method below for reference.
`Action<object> action = (object obj) =>{`
`CreateUserNotifications(notification, users);`
`};`
`Task createTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(action,"NotificationCreationTask" + notification.NotificationId);`

Answer (score 1):

Do it in another thread instead of using BackgroundWorker. I am not sure about BackGroudWorker will work in this context.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         ...
       // I need this to finish before the response ends
       CalendarEvent event = CreateCalendarEvent();
       List<int> users = GetUsersFromDB();
       if(event != null) // The event was created successfully so create the notifications
       {

             Thread thread = new Thread(
            () =>
             {
                CreateUserNotifications(notification, users);
             });
             thread .IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();

       } else {
            ...
            // Log Error and set status code for response
            ...
         }
         ...
         context.Response.End()
    }
```